# Value of a product of cosines and the floor of its reciprocal

Tags: trigonometry, products, ceiling-and-floor-functions

1. $$
   \mbox{The question states}\quad
   {a \over b}
   =\prod_{n = 1 \atop{\vphantom{\LARGE A}n \not= 9}}^{17}\cos\left(n\pi \over 18\right)
   $$
2. $$\mbox{And it is also provided that}\quad
   \left\lfloor{b \over a}\right\rfloor = 85^{2} + 7^{2} + \lambda
   $$

The task is to **find the value of $\lambda$**.

---

I haven't even been able to make sense of the first expression and reduce it to a sensible form. I am open to all kinds of suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a well-known identity:
$$ \prod_{n=1}^{N-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{N}\right) = \frac{2N}{2^N}\tag{1} $$
that can be proved through De Moivre's formula and/or Chebyshev polynomials.
Take $N=9$ and re-arrange to get:
$$ \prod_{\substack{1\leq n\leq 17 \\ n\neq 9}}\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{18}\right)=\frac{9}{65536}\tag{2}$$
from which $\lambda=\color{red}{7}$.

Comment: Can you please link to the proof? Or better yet, explain it in the simplest manner possible?

Comment: @ambigram_maker: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002039893&IDDOC=178038

Comment: Can you please verify that the value of $\frac{a}{b}=-\frac{36}{2^{18}}$. Then do I use binomial theorem to proceed?

Comment: @ambigram_maker: that product ($(2)$) is for sure positive.

Comment: Oh yes... I didn't notice $(-1)^8$ while factoring out the second half.